# Where is the MySQL variable - innodb_flush_method?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5, configuration

I would like to tweak the value of [innodb_flush_method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) to find out its performance impact on a database server. That variable is listed when I run the command `SHOW VARIABLES`.

But I could not find it in the configuration file for the MySQL Server - `my.cnf`.
I'm using [XAMPP 1.6.3](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/news-article,105087.html) with PHP (5.2.3) and MySQL (5.0.45). Its MySQL configuration file path is **/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf**
I searched the variable in the file, but no luck.
Where can I find it? Am I just overlooking?

**UPDATE**
I upgraded to [XAMPP 1.8.1](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html). Its configuration file path is **/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini**
Still could not find that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for you to have it is to add it to your `my.cnf`.

Before you can add this option, you must make sure the InnoDB storage engine is available.

Please run these commands

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb';
SHOW ENGINES;
```

If you see this:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb';
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| have_innodb   | DISABLED |
+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW ENGINES;
+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Engine     | Support  | Comment                                                        |
+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT  | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         |
| MEMORY     | YES      | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      |
| InnoDB     | NO       | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     |
| BerkeleyDB | NO       | Supports transactions and page-level locking                   |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES      | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) |
| EXAMPLE    | NO       | Example storage engine                                         |
| ARCHIVE    | YES      | Archive storage engine                                         |
| CSV        | YES      | CSV storage engine                                             |
| ndbcluster | DISABLED | Clustered, fault-tolerant, memory-based tables                 |
| FEDERATED  | YES      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES      | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          |
| ISAM       | NO       | Obsolete storage engine                                        |
+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

then you have `skip-innodb` in your my.cnf. You should comment it out and restart mysql

What you want to see is this:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_innodb   | YES   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW ENGINES;
+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Engine     | Support  | Comment                                                        |
+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT  | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         |
| MEMORY     | YES      | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      |
| InnoDB     | YES      | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     |
| BerkeleyDB | NO       | Supports transactions and page-level locking                   |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES      | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) |
| EXAMPLE    | NO       | Example storage engine                                         |
| ARCHIVE    | YES      | Archive storage engine                                         |
| CSV        | YES      | CSV storage engine                                             |
| ndbcluster | DISABLED | Clustered, fault-tolerant, memory-based tables                 |
| FEDERATED  | YES      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES      | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          |
| ISAM       | NO       | Obsolete storage engine                                        |
+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Add that option to the `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

then run

```
service mysql restart
```

Afterwards, you should be able to see it if you run

```
mysql> show variables like 'innodb_flush_method';
+---------------------+----------+
| Variable_name       | Value    |
+---------------------+----------+
| innodb_flush_method | O_DIRECT |
+---------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## UPDATE 2013-04-12 14:25 EDT

I just realized you are running the Windows version of MySQL. What was I thinking ?

As point by @yercube's comment, [**`innodb_flush_method`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) is not available for Windows. Here is the MySQL Documentation on it:

> Controls the system calls used to flush data to the InnoDB data files and log files, which can influence I/O throughput. This variable is relevant only for Unix and Linux systems. On Windows systems, the flush method is always async_unbuffered and cannot be changed.

If you need this performance enhancement, migrate your data to the Linux version of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, Rolando. I found that `have_innodb=YES` and `#skip-innodb`. So, InnoDB engine is already available. When I added `innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT` under the `[mysqld]` section, I could not restart mysql. I got the error "**Windows could not start the mysql service on Local Computer. Error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly**". When I removed that line, I could restart the server. I could not add that variable anywhere in the file. Any idea?

Comment: OMG it just hit me. This is a Windows question. For the Windows version of MySQL, `O_DIRECT` is not supported. It is available under Linux only.

Comment: Yep: *"On Windows, the flush method is always `async_unbuffered` and cannot be changed."*

Comment: Another FacePalm Moment : http://www.mamapop.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/yet_another_picard_facepalm_flip.jpg